# Recognize the custom speech keywords (Unity, MRTK, Hololens 1)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, speech, mrtk

I'm trying to get the hololens (1) to recognize a custom defined speech keyword.  Using Unity and MRTK.  It recognizes the pre-defined keywords (ex: "Select") but my custom keyword (let's call it "Keyword") isn't recognized.

I have both a tooltip pop up to give feedback if it recognized a keyword and a audio feedback I put in there for debugging purposes (aka: if ANY keyword is recognized, play a chime).  It works for "Select" but not for "Keyword."

I want this keyword to be globally recognized.

1. Microphone capability is selected.
2. Keyword is defined in the profiles section. (Input>Speech>Add a New Speech Command)
3. Input Action Handler, Speech Input Handler, and a custom code "SpeechManager.cs" ALL do the same thing.  "Select" is recognized (pop up and chime played) but "Keyword" is not.
4. "Focus Required" is not selected.
5. I have tried several different keywords to make sure I didn't pick a difficult to recognize one.

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
   using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
   public class SpeechManager : MonoBehaviour, IMixedRealitySpeechHandler
   {

   void Start()
   {
       //Debugging "play sound" declarations deleted as not important for this example script.
       CoreServices.InputSystem?.RegisterHandler<IMixedRealitySpeechHandler>(this);
   }

   void IMixedRealitySpeechHandler.OnSpeechKeywordRecognized(SpeechEventData eventData)
   {
       PlaySound(1);  //DEBUG AUDIO FEEDBACK

       if (eventData.Command.Keyword == "keyword")
       {
           PlaySound(2);  //DEBUG AUDIO FEEDBACK
       }
       else if (eventData.Command.Keyword == "select")
       {
           PlaySound(3);  //DEBUG AUDIO FEEDBACK
       }
   }
   }
   ```

What SHOULD happen:

"Select" spoken: PlaySound(1) and PlaySound(3) triggered.

"Keyword" spoken: PlaySound(1) and PlaySound(2) triggered.

What ACTUALLY happens:

"Select": PlaySound(1) triggered*

"Keyword" nothing happens <- Why?  WHY???

'* Yes, PlaySound(3) is not triggered, but that is a whole separate issue that I'm not too concerned about because both Speech Input Handler and Input Action Handler both recognize "Select."  One issue at a time!

Comment: why are you using 'select'? I guess its already reserved, because this speech command works in every application on the hololens. Did you check if `Start Behavior` under `MRT>Input>Speech` is set to `Auto Start`? Did you try different `Recognition Confidence Level`? If you attached the `Speech Input Handler` to an Gameobject, was it activated in the scene on runtime?

Comment: I used 'select' specifically because i knew it would be recognized.  It allows me to confirm that the Speech Input Handler is working correctly, that the speech recognition is functioning, and that keywords are getting passed to Speech input handler.  It allows me to pin point where the problem is.

Comment: Start Behavior is set to Auto Start.  Good question.  I have not tried different confidence levels.  I figure if it can hear "select" then it should be able to hear something else.  I did try different word of different lengths and said them many (many) times.

Answer (score 1):

Perazim, thank you for your input.  Mine looks exactly like yours. So why wasn't it working?  I figured it out.  Another user on another problem solved their problem by deleting the App folder (or whatever you named your build folder).  So i thought, let's give it a try.  It worked!!!  Tip to save you massive amount of time: if you think it should work and it doesn't, delete App!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can share how I set up my scene and my words are getting recognized. I attach the `SpeechInputHandler` e.g. on my toolbar and reference my keywords to the toolbar buttons. `Is Focus Required` is also set to `false`.
 1. Define your keyword under `MRT>Input>Speech`:
[image]
 2. Setup the `Speech Input Handler`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the newer speech platform. It supports unity, and it's available here: http://aka.ms/speech/sdk. Some find it easier to use.

You can checkout a Unity quick start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/speech-to-text-from-microphone?tabs=unity%2Cx-android%2Clinux%2Cjava-runtime&pivots=programming-language-csharp)